Commutator of angular momentum operator $[\hat{l}_a, F_b(\hat{x})]$ with a position-dependent vector-function $\vec{F}(\vec{x})$?
If we derive it using the theory of infinitesimal rotations, we get $$[\hat{l}_a, F_d(\hat{x})] = i \epsilon_{adg} F_g(\hat{x}) - i\epsilon_{abc}x_b\frac{\partial F_d}{\partial x_c}.$$
But if we use the definition $$\hat{l}_a = -i\epsilon_{abc}x_b \partial_c$$ and just substitute into the commutator (in analogy to this answer), we get
$$[\hat{l}_a, F_d(\hat{x})] = [ -i\epsilon_{abc}x_b \partial_c,F_d(\hat{x})] = -i\epsilon_{abc}x_b\frac{\partial F_d}{\partial x_c}$$
The question is, why did this happen? Why doesn't the substitution by definition give the first term? Is this somehow related to spin?
Edit : I also forgot to write, but for a space-independant vector, we get the first term $$[\hat{l}_a, F_d] = i \epsilon_{adg} F_g. $$ Is this somehow related to something as well?

Edit: Fine, I understood that maybe it's because the formula for the operator $\hat{l}_a$ is in the case when the particle doesn't have a spin and electrical charge. But I still would like to know what went wrong here ...

I may have messed up some signs

When you write
$$
\hat{l}_a = -i\epsilon_{abc}x_b \partial_c
$$
Actually what you're doing is to write it in position basis $| x\rangle$. The expression
$$
\hat l_a F_d(\hat x) = -i\epsilon_{abc}x_b {\partial F_d\over \partial x_c}
$$
Is only true if $F$ could be diagonalized in position basis, with $F(\hat x) |x\rangle = F(x)|x\rangle$. If it could not, we should write
$$
\hat l_a F_d(\hat x) |\psi\rangle = \int dx' (-i)\epsilon_{abc} x_b \partial_c \langle x|F(\hat x)|x'\rangle \psi(x').
$$
Now, maybe it would sound strange, since the most general definition of a function of an operator like $F(\hat x)$ would be through the spectrum of $\hat x$, i.e., by defining it's diagonalizable in the position basis. If it could not, we should have another definition for a position of an operator, for example through Taylor series.
For a operator to be of vector type, it should satisfy a rule about how it rotates. Probably you considered that deriving the first expression. It happens that these operators sometimes does not commute with position, so it possibly can't be diagonalized in position basis. I didn't check it, but if to choose one of those two, I would go for the first.
By sanity check, if $F_d \neq F_d(\hat x)$, your first expression recovers the usual commutation relation for vector operators. If now $F_d(\hat x)$ is a scalar type operator, again your first expression recovers the right expression.

Thank you for your answer!! Where exactly in the 'stupid' commutator computation is the fact that F can be diagonalized in the position basis used, though??

I think it is very subtle, but do note it we need to redo what was done in the answer you linked in a more careful way. First projecting the commutator in position basis, $\langle x| [l_a,F_d(\hat x)] |\psi\rangle $, after inserting an identity $\mathbb I = \int dx' |x\rangle!\langle x| $ between the commutator and the state, and then working each component.

To "substitute" $p_a$ by $-i\partial_a$ is a careless movement. Actually what you're doing is exactly to project in the position basis $\langle x|p_a$ and using known results about momentum operator.

Another question -- how do I check that the vector field operator doesn't commute with position ?
