Angular momentum operator formula
As I was browsing Wikipedia, I encountered this phrase:
In the special case of a single particle with no electric charge and no spin, the orbital angular momentum operator can be written in the position basis as: $$L = − i \hbar ( r \times \nabla )$$
Why is this only true in the case of no spin? What changes if a particle has spin?

possible duplicate of this post.

It is poor wording, I believe it is just trying to emphasize that this orbital angular momentum is also the total angular momentum. On the other hand, a more formal way to write angular momentum for a spinful particle would be: $$\mathbf{L}=-i\hbar\left(\mathbf{r}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\right)\otimes\mathbf{1}$$
Where $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity in the spin space. So for a spin-half particle, you'd get: $$\mathbf{L}=-i\hbar\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{r}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla} & 0 \\
0 & \mathbf{r}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Or: $$\mathbf{L}=-i\hbar\left[\begin{pmatrix}
y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & 0 \\
0 & y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{\hat{i}}+\begin{pmatrix}
z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
0 & z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{\hat{j}}+\begin{pmatrix}
x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
0 & x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{\hat{k}}\right]$$

You are wrong, I'm pretty sure of it. You cannot always blindly use this expression if a particle has a spin : see my other  question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837232/

I mean, in my question, if we replace F with \psi and think for some time, we will get something like j = l + s
